# Indefinite while loop not exited by giving it empty str

Tags: python

Can someone please explain to me why this program returns an error about not being able to convert `''` to `int`? I know it can't be converted, but why does it even go into the while loop after entering `''`?

```py
x = input('Enter a number: ')
difference = 0

while str(x) != '':
    y = x
    x = input()
    if difference < int(y) - int(x):
        difference = int(y) - int(x)
else:
    print(difference)
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Programing\Python\Uloha.py", line 7, in <module>
        if difference < int(y) - int(x):
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: Where do you initially define `x`?

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: `x` *is* defined. There was just a formatting problem.

Comment: You need to initialize `x` if you are going to check first in the while statement.  When the code reahes `while(str(x) != ''):`, x is not defined

Comment: If x is defined above, then please share full error traceback for us to evaluate and provide feedback

Comment: We still need the full error traceback to be certain of where the error has occurred.

Comment: `Exception has occurred: ValueError
invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
  File "E:\Programing\Python\Uloha.py", line 7, in <module>
    if(rozdiel<(int(y) - int(x))):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not checking if `x` equals `''` in between getting it via `input` and attempting to pass it to `int`:

```py
    x = input()
    if difference < int(y) - int(x):
```

It's *already* in the while loop at that point. You could rearrange things like this:

```py
y = x = input('Enter a number: ')
difference = 0

while x != '':
    new_difference = int(y) - int(x)
    if difference < new_difference:
        difference = new_difference
    y = x
    x = input()

print(difference)
```

This way it will check the condition after `input`, and only run the loop again if `x` isn't `''`.

Also note that `x` is already a string, so `str(x)` is unnecessary, and there's no need to calculate the new difference twice each time. (The `else` isn't necessary here either, since there's no possibility you'll break out of the loop.)